# .NET 5 (NET Core 5) use libraries built against .NET Framework 4 - compatibility shim?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-5

I have 3rd party libraries (dlls with .net assemblies) that were compiled against .NET Framework 4.6. I'm quite sure they don't use any net-framework-only stuff, i.e. if I had access to sources, I could just as well compile them against .NET Core 3 or .NET 5.
I know I can't reference such libraries directly from .NET Core, but I've seen mentions of some compatibility shims.

Is there an easy way to somehow reference such .NET Framework dlls from .NET 5?

Comment: Wrap them up as NuGet package and cheat .NET Core to consume them if you are so sure.

Comment: _I'm quite sure they don't use any net-framework-only stuff_ You'll probably need .net standard then

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski What do you mean? The situation is - there is a dll that's already built against NetFramework. I just have the dll. The project that needs to use it is in .NET 5. Is it feasible to consume that dll?

Comment: @LexLi Thank you, would be cool to get a bit more instructions about that - maybe as an answer that I can accept? Trying to cook up something now, never built nuget packages.

Comment: All I said can be divided and searched on the internet, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package I don't want to leave a lengthy answer, as probably not many people will go this strange way.

Comment: @LexLi Ok, thank you, that's what I've been doing.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to migrate the .NET Framework libraries over to .NET Standard. This will allow you to use them in both .NET Core and .NET 5 projects. You'll need to make sure you migrate to an appropriate version of .NET Standard, so that you ensure compatibility with the various projects you wish to use them in. I'll provide a link to the docs section that outlines the version compatibilities as well as other info that may be useful.

If you're correct in saying that the existing libraries aren't using any .NET Framework specific features, then it will probably be a rather simple migration. The docs have guides for how to migrate from version to version.

I'm not aware of any "hacky" methods to get around it easily. Depending on how important these libraries are to you, it may or may not be worth it but that's up to you. If you're going to be using them often for future projects, then it's probably worthwhile to go ahead and migrate them.

Just make sure you use the correct .NET Standard version for your use case. Depending on the version(s) of .NET Core you'll be using them in, that could change things.

Docs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Why are you offering to migrate? I said explicitly that I can't do that.